# Compact normed vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Let $V$ be a normed vector space.If $V\neq \{0\}$ is it true that our space cannot be compact?

Comment: It depends on definition of "normed" if you mean: real or complex vector space endowed with the topology induced by a norm, then it is true as $span(v)$ is homeomorphic to either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^2$ hence is not compact. but $span(v)$ is closed and closed in compacts are compact

Answer (score 5):

Here is a compact normed vector space. Let $\mathbb F_2$ be the field with two elements $0,1$. Then $V:=\mathbb F_2$ is a $\mathbb F_2$ vector space. With the norm
$$
\|v\|:= \begin{cases} 0  & v=0\\ 1 & v=1\end{cases}
$$
is becomes a normed vector space. Of course, it is compact.

Seriously, normed vector spaces are usually defined over the reals or complex numbers. Then if $V\ne \{0\}$ there is a non-zero vector $v\in V$. Now consider the sequence $v_n:=n\cdot v$. This sequence does not have a convergent subsequence, hence $V$ cannot be compact.

Comment: More generally, normed vector spaces are defined over normed fields (i.e. fields with an absolute value). The same (more or less) argument as the one you have supplied works if the base field is not compact, otherwise, it is clearly not true (as your example with the two-element field, or an analogous example with another finite field with trivial absolute value shows).

Answer (score 1):

A norm always implies a vector space over the field $\mathscr{F}$ of real or complex numbers. For any unit vector $x \ne 0$,  the set $\{ \alpha x : \alpha \in \mathscr{F} \}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathscr{F}$, which is definitely not compact.

Answer (score 0):

A normed real vector space is also a metric space. A metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded (in particular, complete and bounded). No non-zero real vector space is bounded  so no such space is compact. A similar argument holds for complex vector spaces.